# What are the differences between the Wireless Scanner vs Emitter?

Tags: invisible-inc

On one mission, I acquired a Wireless Scanner gadget:

> WIRELESS SCANNER
>
> Passively scans for Mainframe devices within range.
>
> Requires HACKING Skill Level 2

I found this item to be a little underwhelming, considering that I started my campaign with the agent Internationale, who has the Wireless Emitter augment (emphasis mine):

> WIRELESS EMITTER
>
> Allows agent to hack items from a distance, through walls.
>   *Automatically reveals nearby mainframe objects.*

Other than the fact that the Emitter actually allows me to hack consoles from a distance, while the Scanner does not, are there any other differences between these two items? Does the Scanner have a greater range, or is the range the same as the Emitter?

Answer (score 6):

Like many items, the Wireless Scanner comes in a few different grades (I, II and III) that vary in cost, performance and requirements. According to the [wikia Gadgets page](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Gadgets) the three grades require a hacking skill of 2, 3 and 4 respectively and scan for mainframe devices at a range of 4, 6 and 8 tiles respectively. The version you seem to have run across is the lowest grade (based on the hacking skill requirement).

Internationale's Wireless Emitter has the added ability that it can hack console from a distance, with a range of 6.

Thus, while Wireless Scanner III has a larger scanning range than Internationale's Wireless Emitter, the Wireless Scanners are generally inferior.